# Using a function name that is already taken

Tags: c++

Let's assume some third-party developer writes a function

```
int GetErrorCode(const object * p);
```

This function returns only certain `int` values, thus I am tempted to write my own `ErrorCode` enum class, that contains all the possible return values. Then write a bit updated function:

```
enum class ErrorCode : int {};
ErrorCode GetErrorCode2(const object * p){
  return (ErrorCode)GetErrorCode(p);
}
```

The problem is I want my function to be named `GetErrorCode` and not that less-intuitive `GetErrorCode2`.

How can I possibly achieve that? Maybe there is a way to swap function names or something?

Answer (score 11):

Use namespaces:

```
namespace MyLibrary {

    ErrorCode GetErrorCode(const object *p) {
        int origResult = ::ErrorCode(p); 
        // use :: to explicitly call outer function to avoid recursion
        ...
    }

}
```

Then you can call the function as:

```
MyLibrary::GetErrorCode(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your function in a namespace that you normally use. You might have a `using namespace foo;` - er better yet, `using foo::GetErrorCode;` - for it where you use it, preferably in a function's body.

Comment: I'd advice against `using namespace foo;` - it pulls in *everything* and polutes the global namespace with more than you need. Prefer more specific `using foo::func;` to just pull in the specific stuff you need and do so in as narrow a scope as possible. Or just stick to fully qualifying what you use `foo::func();`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Agree. 'where you use it' is supposed to mean function body, but `using foo::func` is even better - editing..

Comment: The using statement will just make the name conflict appear again, you're bringing the name clash back by doing that.

Comment: @rubenvb: using within a function is acceptable IMHO (otherwise we wouldn't have it). It's headers using namespaces that mean the real problem. Using a function is somewhere in-between. I wouldn't throw out these language features just because too generic use might mean issues.

Comment: @lorro: unless you can 100% guarantee that the original (conflicting) function declaration is never pulled in through some or other header, you'll get [this situation, leading to an error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/417e44357b277c93). So no, `using` to pull in reused function names is not a good idea in general. In fact, since it's an external library, you can never be sure the authors won't decide to pull in or forward declare that function name in a conflicing manner. Hey, it's part of the API, so it'll appear somewhere in the include chain, right?

Comment: Anyways, putting the wrapper in the same namespace as all the rest of the stuff actually using the function will rid you of having to fully qualify it everywhere. So in practice, the `using` won't even be necessary.